# How to inject private field into tested object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have following class:

```
public class TestedClass{
   private List<String> strings;
   .... 
}
```

Test:

```
public class TestedClassTest{

  @Spy
  TestedClass testedClass = new TestedClass();

}
```

I know that exists annotation `@InjectMocks` but it works only for mocks but I want to inject real `List`

### P.S.

List have not setter. In real code setter is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TestedClassTest{
  @Spy
  private List<String> strings;

  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  TestedClass testedClass = new TestedClass();

}
```